# SQL Server Overall Total in a group by

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server Query, I am trying to count the number of employees per site. This works, but when I try to add in a percentage of total, it still groups by Site so it is inaccurate.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

I am using this Query to create a view.

```
select Site.SiteName,
sum(case when Employee.ActiveStatus = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as 
"NumberOfEmployees",
CONVERT(decimal(6,2),(sum(case when Employee.ActiveStatus = 'Yes' then 1 
else 0 end))/(convert(decimal(6,2),COUNT(EmployeeID)))) as PercentageOfEmps

from Employee
left join Site
on(Employee.SiteID=Site.SiteID)
GROUP BY Site.SiteName;
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```
select 
  Site.SiteName,
  NumberOfEmployees = sum(case when Employee.ActiveStatus = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end),
  PercentageOfEmps = CONVERT(decimal(6,2),(sum(case when Employee.ActiveStatus = 'Yes' then 1 
else 0 end))/(SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM Employee)
from Employee
left join Site
  on Employee.SiteID=Site.SiteID
GROUP BY Site.SiteName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide an answer for your scenario, as I don't have any sample data to use, therefore I've provided a small dataset.

One method is to use a CTE/Subquery to get a total number and then include the total in the `GROUP BY`. This method avoids 2 scans of the table:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Steve',1),
                (2,'Jayne',1),
                (3,'Greg',2),
                (4,'Sarah',3)) V(EmpID, EmpName, SiteID)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT V.EmpID,
           V.EmpName,
           V.SiteID,
           COUNT(V.EmpID) OVER () AS TotalCount
    FROM VTE V)
SELECT C.SiteID,
       COUNT(C.EmpID) AS Employees,
       COUNT(C.EmpID) / (C.TotalCount *1.0) AS Perc
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.SiteID,
         C.TotalCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

This script should help-

```
SELECT 
Site.SiteName,
COUNT(EmployeeID) AS [NumberOfEmployees],
((COUNT(EmployeeID)*1.0)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employee WHERE ActiveStatus = 'Yes'))*100.00 as PercentageOfEmps
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Site
    ON Employee.SiteID = Site.SiteID
WHERE Employee.ActiveStatus = 'Yes'
GROUP BY Site.SiteName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data creation script
    `declare @Employee Table(EmployeeID int ,ActiveStatus nvarchar(20) ,SiteID int)
    declare @Site Table(SiteName nvarchar(20) ,SiteID int)
    insert into @Employee values(1,'Yes',101),(2,'Yes',101),(3,'Yes',102),(4,'Yes',102), 
    (5,'Yes',101)`

```
insert into @Site values('Site1',101)
insert into @Site values('Site2',102)
```

//real script to get the %percentage
`;with cte as 
(
select s.SiteName,sum(case when e.ActiveStatus = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as "NumberOfEmployees"
from @Employee e
left join @Site s
on(e.SiteID=s.SiteID)
GROUP BY s.SiteName
),
cte_sum as 
(select sum(NumberOfEmployees) as total from cte  )
select c.*, convert (decimal(6,2),c.NumberOfEmployees)/convert (decimal(6,2),cs.total)*100 from cte_sum cs, cte c;`